# CORS setting on google cloud bucket

Tags: cors, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to configure CORS on a google bucket.I want to set CORS config every time i create a new bucket. I want to get this done by  Cloud Storage Client Libraries, not using XML API. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None of the [Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) in any language appear to provide the ability to directly set the CORS config. So it seems the only options are either to use [the XML API with the `cors` param](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-bucket-cors) or else to do it from the command line [using `gsutil` and a JSON config file](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#Configuring-CORS-on-a-Bucket), like this:

```
gsutil cors set cors-json-file.json gs://[my-bucket]
```

Where `cors-json-file.json` is something like this:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes, This is one way. I forgot to mention I want to get this done every time I create a bucket. So is there a setter and getter method??

Comment: As far as I know none of the Cloud Storage Client Libraries in any language provide a direct way to do it. So to do it programmatically (rather than from the command line with gsutil), I think the only thing available is the XML API https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-bucket-cors

Comment: I have not worked with applications creating web services through HTTP requests, so was reluctant on using XML API. Can you shed some light on how to do that??

Comment: The way you use the XML API is just to take whatever HTTP client library your programming language provides, and construct a request with the appropriate API endpoint and with an appropriate XML document as the body. The specific details of course depend on what language you’re using. But if you want more help with that, I think you’ll get some good responses if you post it as a separate question (and I will try to respond to it myself).

Comment: Note that if you run `gsutil cors get gs://[bucket]` and it shows the correct headers, then sometimes you have to wait 1 or 2 hours for Google Storage to propagate these changes.