# Cors Error When Using Google Cloud Storage getSignedUrl Put Axios

Tags: cors, google-cloud-storage, axios, firebase-storage, pre-signed-url

I've created a signedUrl via Firebase functions

```
let gcsBucket = admin.storage().bucket();
let gcsBucketFile = gcsBucket.file('videos/' + videoId + '/' + 'video')
let signedUrls = await gcsBucketFile.getSignedUrl({ action: 'write', expires: '03-09-2491', contentType: 'image/png'})
let signedUrl = signedUrls[0]
```

Everything works great and it gives me the signedUrl. But when I try and use this signedUrl on the front end/in my browser I get cors error:

```
 let file =  e.target.files[0]
 var options = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'image/png'
    }
  };

 return axios.put( signedUrl , file, options )...
```

I get the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://storage.googlea...' from origin 
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight 
request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header 
is present on the requested resource.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768136/cors-on-firebase-storage/47779318#47779318, which explains the steps you need to follow to CORS-enable the endpoint. The error message cited in the question specifically indicates the endpoint isn’t yet configured to respond to COR preflight OPTIONS request in the right way. Following the steps in that answer should fix that.

Comment: Amazing. that worked! Any security issue's I should be consider or aware of after adding cors?.... my config was easy [
    {
      "origin": ["https://website.com"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "method": ["GET", "PUT", "HEAD"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]

Comment: There are no security issues I know of that you should be aware of with that config. So I think you’re good to go 