# How to download a pdf from Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, webclient

I was getting this error when I try to download a pdf from Firebase Storage: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at "document.pdf" from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` Now I have configured the cors.js of my bucket to not have any restriction. But when I click on the button download, nothings opens and nothing is downloaded.

I have a button in my web page that onClick it calls the function `downloadInvoice()` on the client-side:

```
function downloadInvoice(){
    var invoiceRef = firebase.storage().ref('pedidos/' + id +'.pdf');

    // Get the download URL
    invoiceRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
    // This can be downloaded directly:
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function(event) {
        var blob = xhr.response;
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
    }).catch(function(error) {

        // A full list of error codes is available at
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
        switch (error.code) {
            case 'storage/object-not-found':
            // File doesn't exist
            break;

            case 'storage/unauthorized':
            // User doesn't have permission to access the object
            break;

            case 'storage/canceled':
            // User canceled the upload
            break;

            case 'storage/unknown':
            // Unknown error occurred, inspect the server response
            break;
        }
    });
}
```

The URL is correct because when I had the error I can open the document from the console of the browser.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768136/cors-on-firebase-storage)

Comment: No, I no longer have this problem. What I need now is to download the doc because nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: Okey, I found something like this `window.open(url, '_blank').focus();`

Comment: Hello @EmiliBellotPulido, I'm having the same problem, nothing happens when I click the button, how did you managed to solved it?